# How to fix the Error in static member that is private?

Tags: c++, variables, static, declaration, member

Why i is being called private?as i is static member ,then it must not an error in line no.19

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class myClass{
    static int i;
public:
    void seti(int a)
    {
        i=a;
    }
    int geti()
    {
        return i;
    }
};
int myClass::i;
int main()
{
    myClass ob1,ob2;
    cout<<myClass::i<<endl;
    ob1.seti(200);
    cout<<ob1.geti()<<endl;
    cout<<ob2.geti()<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the language name?

Comment: Make `i` public or don't try to access it directly?

Comment: @IvoMerchiers C++

Answer (score 0):

Here the issue is that member attributes of a `class` are `private` by default. That means that `i` is private and that you can't access it from outside your class.

One solution would be to declare `i` as a public member.

```
class myClass{
public:
    static int i;
    void seti(int a)
    {
        i=a;
    }
    int geti()
    {
        return i;
    }
};
```

PS : members of a `struct` are public by default